# Bulkcopy data without sorting

Tags: sql-server, powershell

we are bulk copying data from a csv file to sql table using code below. it works great, but one suggestion we received is to retain the order of the source data, i.e. do not sort it, because they connect eventually to a database in excel that has this data as is from the sql table, and its sorted currently which they wish its not.
So the question is: how can we bulkcopy the data into the sql table in the order it is in the csv file, i.e. without sorting?

something like this? pseudocode:

```
$sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer($CSVDataTable)| No-sort
```

csv file (unsorted):

```
Report Year
2013
2014
2015
2016
2017
2018
2021
2022
2023
2024
2025
2026
2027
2028
2029
2019 0+12
2019 12+0
2019 8+4
2020 0+12
2020 1+11
BP19
BP20
```

sql table after bulkcopy (sorted):

[image: sql table]

code:

```
$CSVDataTable = Import-Csv $csvFile | Out-DataTable

# Build the sqlbulkcopy connection, and set the timeout to infinite
$sqlBulkCopy = New-Object ("Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy") -ArgumentList $SqlConnection
$sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "$schemaName.[$csvFileBaseName]"
$sqlBulkCopy.bulkcopyTimeout = 0
$sqlBulkCopy.batchsize = 50000
$sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "$schemaName.[$csvFileBaseName]"

foreach ($column in $CSVDataTable.Columns) { 
    $sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add($column.ColumnName, $column.ColumnName) > $null 
}

$sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer($CSVDataTable)
```

Comment: I don't understand. It shouldn't matter what order the data is copied into the table.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart to some extent, yes it doesnt matter, but our business users apparently want it the way its in the csv file, they dont want it sorted, because in excel, they wanna see it in the "hierarchy" type format they sent us the csv file as.

Comment: If they need an order, specify it when retrieving the data. I would also suggest normalizing the data, but that's not a topic for here.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart a little more details regarding what we are doing: we actually built these sql tables from the csv files we were given, and through that, i built an ssas tabular cube. the business users connect to analysis services in excel to our server that has this cube deployed on, and then they start playing with the data and capabilities this ssas cube gives them in terms of visualization. in order for the cube to have data, we "process" it from the datasource, which is the sql database/tables. i dont have control over the data retrieval/processing unfortunately.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart another option is to add a sequence column with numbers, i.e. 1,2,3,4... to retain the data ordering...but i was hoping to avoid this because i would have to add this to all the csv files...

Comment: Bulk copy doesn't sort data for you. If it's reading the rows in a sorted order it's possibly because the source table has a clustered index on it specifying that ordering.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning wait a minute...i do have a Primary Key ( clustered index ) on the tables! ohhhh so thats the effect of clustered indexing, interesting!

Comment: Yes, a clustered index arranges the table rows in key column(s) order. This is why you can only have one clustered index per table.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning wait, so if I add a sequence column, like 1,2,3, 4...etc as the 1st column of the table, it will still end up sorting based on the primary key? Hmm, so what can I do in that case....I ran outta options...do I form a composite key instead with this sequence column I'd be adding + the current primary key (report year)? Would that make sense/address the sorting issue? Would it impact my foreign key table as well?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning wow it looks like it doesnt retain the order, just tried it out with a sequence column. damn lol, thank you for the tip! i guess theres nothing else we can do about this